# Angular 8: Function expressions are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble trying to build prod build in Angular 8. The error is

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'SocketLibModule'
    'SocketLibModule' references 'initializeApp'
      'initializeApp' contains the error at ../socket-lib/src/lib/socket-lib.module.ts(9,12)
        Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

What points to my lib

```js
export const SOCKET_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<SocketConfig>('SOCKET_CONFIG');

export function initializeApp(socketConfig: SocketConfig) {
  return (uriConfig: any) => {
    return () => uriConfig.load(socketConfig);
  };
}

@NgModule()
export class SocketLibModule {
  public static forRoot(socketConfig: SocketConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SocketLibModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SOCKET_CONFIG,
          useValue: socketConfig
        },
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: initializeApp(socketConfig),
          deps: [ConfigInitService, HttpClientModule],
          multi: true
        },
        HttpClientModule
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

The error point (9,12) refers to this `return (uriConfig: any) => {` just at opening parenthesis.

I've tried to change arrow functions into regular but nothing has changed as well as error point (9,12)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Maybe in the form of a plunkr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
useFactory: initializeApp(socketConfig),
```

This line is the issue.

The app initializer should be a factory : this means it should be

```
useFactory: initializeApp,
```

Otherwise, you are returning a function call, which is forbidden in typescript decorators (not just in Angular, or it's 8th version)

Comment: But I have to pass a data to my initializing function. As you can see `socketConfig` is being passed down the function because I need provided config in `forRoot` to load proper configs

Comment: Sure, but that's not how you do it. You should add `SocketConfig` to your `deps` array instead.

Answer (score 2):

AOT only supports limited functions call.

You can use already provided `SOCKET_CONFIG` instead of wrapping factory in another function:

```
export function initializeApp(uriConfig: ConfigInitService, socketConfig: SocketConfig) {
   return uriConfig.load(socketConfig);
}
```

Provider should look like:

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeApp,
    deps: [ConfigInitService, SOCKET_CONFIG],
    multi: true
},
```